# Why does chrome/Selenium throw an error when disconnected from the Windows 2019 server remote desktop?

Tags: windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, remote-desktop, undetected-chromedriver

I am running a Selenium code in Python on a Windows server with Chrome WebDriver
Everything works fine, but when I disconnect from the remote desktop, it gives an error right away
How can I fix this?

**Example :**

Taking a screenshot gave this error:

> raise exception_class(message,
> screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
> Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000

or

cant click on an element

> Other element would receive the click: div class="mfp-container
> mfp-inline-holder". selenium

**system info :**

- windows server 2019
- chrome Version 103.0.5060.134

Comment: Update the question with the error tracelogs.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium ok